# Entity Framework 6 One to One with Navigation and Cascade Delete

Tags: c#, entity-framework, one-to-one, cascading-deletes, navigation-properties

Im not sure if what im trying to do is possible so here's a description of what i want.

Firstly when i say nvigation i want to do something like the following in code when querying:

```
            using (var db = new DataContext(connString))
            {
                 var person = db.People.Include("Address").First(); // address to be included

                 //other logic                                         
            }
```

So i have 2 entities (Person and Address).

- Person needs a navigation property to Address
- Person can only have one Address
- Address is required for Person
- Address can have multiple persons (Mum and Daughter have the same
  address for example)

So i have 2 People (person) both have the same Address. If i delete Person 1 the address needs to remain as its still linked via Person2. If i then delete Person2 then the address should be deleted (cascaded delete).

So i guess my question is 'Is this possible and if so, how?'

I can do either or but not both :(

Any help would be appreciated. Also here is the code for the simple objects ive created to demonstrate / test.

```
public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int AddressId { get; set; } // needed for nav?

    public virtual Address Address { get; set; } // nav property
}


public class Address
{       
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string AddressLines1 { get; set; }

    public string AddressLines2 { get; set; }

    public string AddressLines3 { get; set; }

    public string PostCode { get; set; }

    public virtual Person Person { get; set; } // needed for one to one?

}
```

ok and here are the fluent api codes, note: one for the one to one that works and one for the navigation - i don't have one for both but the above entities are setup for both as far as i can see.

One-to-One with Cascade deletes (but no navigation property)

```
 modelBuilder.Entity<Person>()
             .HasRequired(s => s.Address)
             .WithRequiredPrincipal(ad => ad.Person)
             .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
```

Builder that defines the navigation but lacks cascade delete functionality (tested and does not cascade delete)

```
 modelBuilder.Entity<Person>()
            .HasRequired(t => t.Address)
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey(t => t.AddressId)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "Address can have multiple persons" means you are dealing with a One-To-Many relationship, not One-To-One (One address can have Many persons). This also means that you should change your Person reference in the Address entity to `public virtual ICollection<Person> Persons`. Also `Person.AddressId` is not needed for navigation as it will be generated automatically by Entity Framework.

Comment: i couldn't see the forest as the trees were in the way :( Thanks a lot! Much appreciated

Comment: In your case should also work cascade on delete. When you delete an address you will delete all related people